# Application cors error with Vue + Node + Nginx

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nginx

Cross-origin request blocked: The Same Origin policy does not allow reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/product (reason: CORS request failed). Status code: (null).2

I have a virtual machine in linux that shares Vue's index.html through NGINX, I'm accessing this index in the browser, through another pc on the same network.. And I try to make a Vue post via Axios/Fetch for the API I created in NODE, which is running in that same VM.. But every time I come across this cors error, I already configured the node code, Vue code, and Nginx configs

Código node:

```
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: '*',
  methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'POST', 'PUT'],
  allowedHeaders: ['X-CSRF-Token', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept', 'Accept-Version', 'Content-Length', 'Content-MD5', 'Content-Type', 'Date', 'X-Api-Version', 'Authorization'],
}));
```

Código Vue

```
          fetch(this.host_node, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data), // substitua "data" pelos dados que deseja enviar na requisição
          })
            .then(response => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Erro na requisição');
              }
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
              // Manipule a resposta da requisição aqui
              console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              // Trate os erros da requisição aqui
              console.error(error);
            });
```

I tried to configure and I was not successful with any of the configurations